# Unable to open X display when trying to run google-chrome on Centos (Rhel 7.5)

Tags: ssh, centos, x11-forwarding

I need to run Google Chrome remotely on a virtual machine using SSH. I do not want xforwarding - I want to utilize the GPU available on the vm. When I try running  `google-chrome` I get following error:

```
[19615:19615:0219/152933.751028:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1512)] Unable to open X display.
```

I've tried to setting my DISPLAY env value to various values:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0
export DISPLAY=:0.0
```

I've also tried replacing 0.0 in abowe examples with different values.

I have `ForwardX11 no` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config
I tried setting up target like this:

```
systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

When I try to run `sudo lshw -C display` i get folowing output:

```
   *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Hyper-V virtual VGA
       vendor: Microsoft Corporation
       physical id: 8
       bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master rom
       configuration: driver=hyperv_fb latency=0
       resources: irq:11 memory:f8000000-fbffffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM204GL [Tesla M60]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 1
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:f0-ef iomemory:f0-ef memory:41000000-41ffffff memory:fe0000000-fefffffff memory:ff0000000-ff1ffffff
```

I've tried to update my gpu drivers by:

```
wget https://www.nvidia.com/content/DriverDownload-March2009/confirmation.php?url=/tesla/375.66/nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-rhel7-375.66-1.x86_64.rpm
yum -y install nvidia-diag-driver-local-repo-rhel7-375.66-1.x86_64.rpm
```

But after that I still see `UNCLIMED` next to my NVIDIA gpu. 
Aby ideas?

Comment: You are trying to launch google chome on your computer from another computer, right ?

Comment: Check if you have a running xorg, it's port is 6000+n (n is the display number)

Comment: I am trying to lunch Chrome from my computer on virtual machine. And to be clear I do not want X forwarding - I want to się the NVIDIA Tesla GPU available on the vm.

Comment: Basic question but necessary: do you have a running xorg on your vm ?

Answer (score 79):

You can try with Xvfb. it does not require additional hardware.

**Install Xvfb if you didn't install it yet and do the following steps.**

```sh
sudo apt-get install -y xvfb
```

**Dependencies to make "headless" chrome/selenium work:**

```sh
sudo apt-get -y install xorg xvfb gtk2-engines-pixbuf
sudo apt-get -y install dbus-x11 xfonts-base xfonts-100dpi xfonts-75dpi xfonts-cyrillic xfonts-scalable
```

**Optional but nifty: For capturing screenshots of Xvfb display:**

```sh
sudo apt-get -y install imagemagick x11-apps
```

**Make sure that Xvfb starts every time the box/vm is booted:**

```sh
Xvfb -ac :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x16 &
export DISPLAY=:99
```

**Run Google Chrome**

```sh
google-chrome
```

Comment: Awesome - this worked for me on Windows with WSL 2.0 and Ubuntu!! You rock!

Comment: Fixed my problem with being unable to run tests with Karma inside WSL 2 Ubuntu. Many thanks.

Comment: This answer definitely needs to go into the documentation or something. Where all other answers failed, installing the virtual screen fixed it.

Comment: Saved the life... worked on gcp compute engine debian11

Comment: Do you need `xorg` This is the first piece of documentation that says you need it to run headless chromium..

Answer (score 4):

Okay guys. I found my problem after 2 hours of going crazy. My box was configured correctly. What you can NOT do, is ssh from one box, to another box, to this box and expect X11 forwarding to play nicely. Without tearing apart the entire network, I found that if I shelled over from the MAIN box to this box ( no double or triple ssh'ing) chrome comes right up as a regular user using CLI. So it was a matter of multiple shells from multiple boxes that made the display say it was set to NOTHING!  Setting the display manually only complicates the problems. Once I shelled directly over to this box from the main outside box, my display was set to 10:0, which is first instance in my configuration. Don't make this mistake, you will waste valuable time.

Answer (score 2):

FWIW, I ran into this when using SSH to log into a Selenium chrome node in a Docker compose stack. Chrome would launch if I invoked it as `root` with `sudo -u seluser google-chrome`, but not if I logged in as `seluser`. The trick turned out to be that `root` had `DISPLAY` set to `:99:0`, and `seluser` didn't have it set at all. If I set it explicitly (either from a `seluser` shell or from the `docker compose exec` command line) it worked.

```sh
$ docker-compose exec -u seluser \
  selenium-chrome \                 # or whatever your service is called
  /bin/bash
seluser@c02cda62b751:/$ export DISPLAY=:99:0
seluser@c02cda62b751:/$ google-chrome http://app.test:3000/home
```

or

```sh
$ docker-compose exec -u seluser -e DISPLAY=:99:0 \
  selenium-chrome \
    google-chrome http://app.test:3000/home
```

That `:99.0` is undocumented, though, so if this isn't working, you might try checking `root`'s `DISPLAY` value with:

```sh
docker-compose exec -u root selenium-chrome bash -c 'echo "${DISPLAY}"'
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with WSL and Ubuntu. I have unininstalled/Reset the ubuntu. After that, I have executed the below command

```
wsl --set-default-version 2
```

then I installed again the Ubuntu, I didn't get `--no-sandbox` issue or any issue.

Hope this will use for someone.