# Tkinter with headless Chrome runs fine on Mac but not on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, tkinter

I'm writing a Python script that opens a link and click on a link to copy content into the clipboard. Then I use Tkinter to pass the content into a variable. Below is part of my script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
chromeOptions.add_argument('window-size=1366x768')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)

driver.get('https://www.example.com')

r = Tk()
r.withdraw()

while not r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD"):
      time.sleep(0.1)

copyResult = r.selection_get(selection="CLIPBOARD")
```

When executing the script on Mac it works flawlessly but on Ubuntu I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeliveryTracking.py", line 52, in <module>
    r = Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 2261, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
```

My Ubuntu server is hosted on Amazon EC2 so there's no GUI. Is that why I'm getting this error on Ubuntu? If yes then what's an alternative? Anyway on Mac I also specified `--headless` argument so by right it shouldn't use any GUI to run the script. I may be wrong though.

### **Edit:**

I've tried installing xvfb by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61043049/5685946). However I'm still getting the following error when executing my script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "DeliveryTracking.py", line 49, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

And if I just run Google Chrome I get this error `[15352:15352:1215/003611.154158:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1426)] Unable to open X display.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't with running chrome in a headless environment, the problem is with running tkinter.  Tkinter requires a display, either a physical display or the case of a linux environment an X11 display. For the most part, that means tkinter can't run in a server environment unless you set up that environment to have a virtual display for the tkinter process (eg: xvfb).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just like I suspected. But I did specify `--headless` on Mac so why is it able to run? I also installed xvfb by following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61043049/5685946 but it didn't work either. I'll edit my question to include xvfb.

Comment: @KelvinLow: tkinter has no "--headless" option.