# Is there a way to run Google Lighthouse tests headlessly?

Tags: google-chrome, amazon-ec2, headless, lighthouse, amazon-linux

So I'm trying to programmatically conduct Google Lighthouse audits on several webpages, and I'm running into an issue. After installing Chrome and node/npm/lighthouse on an Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance, I am able to successfully run LightHouse tests when I initiate a GUI session and run a command from a terminal within the GUI (this launches chrome and conducts the test as usual) but I am unable to do the same thing from the command line.  [This is the error I get when launching lighthouse.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXmue.png)
`ChromeLauncher:error [42565:42565:0516/170626.787500:ERROR:brower_main_loop.cc (1386) Unable to open X display.`

While there are a couple of other errors, I believe this is the one I should be paying attention to, because when I try to just launch Google Chrome, that is the exact error I get, so I am inclined to believe it is an issue with trying to launch on a display.

I've also tried the "--headless" option when launching chrome and get
`[0516/171128.450564:WARNING:headless_browser_main_parts.cc(83)] Cannot create Pref Service with no user data dir. [0516/171128.521499:ERROR:vaapi_wrapper.cc(594)] Could not get a valid VA display [0516/171128.524992:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(426)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is egl`

Another user with a similar question decided to use the Google Pagespeeds API, which will not a be a solution for me-- it needs to be done locally.

Because this works fine on a GUI session with the same server, I really think it's just a display rendering issue, but I don't know how to solve this. Maybe "simulating" a display? I've also tried entering `export DISPLAY=1:0`, which apparently worked for some users and caused me to stop *seeing* the error, but the functionality was still broken when running the audit.

Any help would be so useful!!

Answer (score 0):

Information found in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60304251/unable-to-open-x-display-when-trying-to-run-google-chrome-on-centos-rhel-7-5) was infinitely helpful. Although I still get a slew of errors when I try to launch the browser, I can successfully run LightHouse and audit the pages I want to without any errors.