# Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, chrome-web-driver

When trying to run headless chrome with selenium I am getting this error:

**[1021/151706.155:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(453)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is swiftshader, ANGLE is**

my setup code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1024,768")
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

driver version is 94.0.4606.61
win32

Comment: fyi: everything is working fine when not running headless.

Comment: Spent the last 24 hours debugging the same issue.

Comment: @Gajus any luck?

Comment: Gave up and went back to using CPU based acceleration.

Comment: This did it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316810/unable-to-locate-elements-on-webpage-with-headless-chrome

Comment: Did it in what sense? That issue does not talk about GPU acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error/warning message, but chromium was running just fine for me. I managed to get rid of this message by adding this option to the command line:

```
--disable-features=DefaultPassthroughCommandDecoder
```